# French passport renewal: Must the old passport be returned if one has a valid e-visa using the old passport's number?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, e-visas, french-citizens

I [read](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F37427/1_1?idFicheParent=F21091#1_1) about French passport renewals (Google Translate):

> The old passport must be returned. If it included a visa, it can be kept for the period of validity of this visa.

How about visas that are e-visas (i.e., not appearing on the passport)? Must the old passport be returned if one has a valid e-visa using the old passport's number?

---

Original quote in French:

> L'ancien passeport doit être restitué. S'il comportait un visa, il peut être conservé pendant la durée de validité de ce visa.

Comment: Does the e-visa have an expiration or "good-until" date when the e-visa becomes unusable?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica Thanks, I'm interested in both cases.

Comment: what country's e-visa do you have that you are concerned about, and is it valid past the life of the associated passport anyway?

Comment: @mlc thanks, I'm curious about both cases (visa still valid and visa becomes invalid upon passport expiry).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I would assume that there is no such thing as an e-visa that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport.  In the absence of evidence to the contrary I am voting to close this question as off topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because such e-visas do not exist.

Comment: @phoog a passport doesn't have to be expired to be replaced

Comment: @phoog That didn't seem to convince you, so I posted [Is there any e-visa that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/187965/1810).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have direct experience with this, as I have renewed my passports a dozen times in the last 17 years in HK. They only look at the passport pages. Valid visa sticker? They hand it back. If not, they keep it, no discussion allowed.

I had a HK resident evisa (which, to be fair wasn't linked to a passport number: I had used that passport when applying but HK resident visas are not linked to a particular passport number). Consulate employee refused to hand back my passport: no valid visa sticker in it. Goodbye.

Comment: I and a family member never had a single passport not returned when applying in France, even if they didn't hold any visa (which is weird)

Comment: That's weird indeed. I even asked one of the Consulate staff. He said it's been policy since the introduction of the electronic passports. Before that it was a free for all.