# Is there any e-visa that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-renewals

I read:

> I would assume that there is no such thing as an e-visa that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport. In the absence of evidence to the contrary I am voting to close this question as off topic.

Is there any e-visas that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, e.g. Indian e-visas.

1. Linked to a passport, since the e-visa has the passport number on it.

   [image]
2. Valid beyond the expiration of that passport according to
   [cgisf.gov.in](https://www.cgisf.gov.in/page/e-visa/#:%7E:text=The%20applicant%20must%20travel%20on,e%2DVisa%20has%20been%20granted.):

> The applicant must travel on the passport on which e-Visa has been applied. Entry into India will be allowed on a new passport even if the e-Visa has been granted on the old passport. However, in such cases, the traveler must also carry the old passport on which the e-Visa has been granted.